# Kenmore dishwasher unresponsive

Tags: plumbing, dishwasher

I have Kenmore dishwasher model 2213092N 413. The user interface went unresponsive. The buttons do not operate the unit and the lights on the UI do not come on.

Per the tech sheet I cut power to the dishwasher, ensured all connections to the control unit were snug, disconnected the keypad/UI from the control unit, reassembled the door leaving the keypad disconnected and the door open, reestablished power to the dishwasher, waited a full 7 seconds for the control unit to power up completely, and closed the door.

Nothing happened. No drain motor activation, no noises, nothing. I have furthermore taken the following additional actions:

- Replaced both the control unit and user interface, run the
  same test, and have had the same result.
- Tested the resistance at door latch and that seems to be good.
- Tested the fuse resistance, on both the old and new unit, and measured <3ohms indicating the F600 and F601 fuses in the control units are good.

I would appreciate any advice on what I may have missed or what the next step would be.

Thanks!

Comment: Check your circuit breakers and also make sure it's not plugged into a GFCI outlet that might have tripped.

Comment: Dishwasher is hardwired and requires the breaker to turn on/off power. And, I am detecting power at all parts of the unit with my non-contact voltage tester.

Comment: If possible, and if you have a digital multi meter, try measuring voltage with that. Non contact voltage detectors are notorious for picking up stray voltages.  Mine even picks up voltage on the ground wires.   Even DMMs aren't perfect, when I really want to know if there is real power there, I use a plain old incandescent light bulb.  I have a socket with 2 wires (often used for construction) and touch them across the contacts.   Real power will light it up, random, induced power won't but will trigger a DMM or a NC voltage detector.

Comment: It is odd to me that both control units are having the same issue. Either they are both defective or they are both good and the issue is caused by something else. You're suggesting that maybe there is in not enough power getting to the control unit itself? Or, they are both facing the same issue which is not distributing enough power to run any downstream components.